# Pausar uma AsyncTask até que uma tarefa seja concluida

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Em minha AsyncTask eu instancio 4 novos objetos, só que eu tenho que ficar nela até que todos os objetos sejam trazidos. Segue o código:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    new CrtlComentario(contexto).trazer(post.getCodigo(), new CallbackTrazer() {
        @Override
        public void resultadoTrazer(Object obj) {
            c = (Comentario) obj;
            flag[3] = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void falha() {
            flag[3] = false;
        }

    });

    new CrtlUsuario(contexto).trazer(c.getUsuarioPost(), new CallbackTrazer() {
        @Override
        public void resultadoTrazer(Object obj) {
            u = (Usuario) obj;
            flag[0] = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void falha() {
            flag[0] = false;
        }
    });

    new CrtlComentarioPost(contexto).listar(new CallbackListar() {
        @Override
        public void resultadoListar(List<Object> lista) {
            for (Object obj : lista)
                cp.add((ComentarioPost) obj);
            flag[1] = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void falha() {
            flag[1] = false;
        }
    });

    new CrtlCurtidaComentario(contexto).listar(new CallbackListar() {
        @Override
        public void resultadoListar(List<Object> lista) {
            for (Object obj : lista)
                cc.add((CurtidaComentario) obj);
            flag[2] = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void falha() {
            flag[2] = false;
        }
    });

    return null;

}
```

Os únicos objetos que nunca poderão ser nulos são o "c" e o "u" os outros dois podem.

Eu preciso que "c" esteja carregado para poder carregar os outros três, pois preciso do seu código.

Eu tentei fazer um while para ficar até eles acabarem usando a variável flag[], mas não funciona e as vezes nem executa a task.

Answer (score 1):

O facto de tanto o método `trazer()` e `listar()` receberem um *Callback* dá ideia que eles são assíncronos.

Se assim é não é necessário utilizar uma *AsyncTask*.

Como precisa do primeiro objecto para "trazer" o segundo, o que deve fazer é "trazer" o segundo no método `resultadoTrazer()` do *Callback* do primeiro.

Qualquer coisa assim:

```
new CrtlComentario(contexto).trazer(post.getCodigo(), new CallbackTrazer() {
    @Override
    public void resultadoTrazer(Object obj) {
        c = (Comentario) obj;

        //*** Talvez colocar em um método **************

        new CrtlUsuario(contexto).trazer(c.getUsuarioPost(), new CallbackTrazer() {
            @Override
            public void resultadoTrazer(Object obj) {
                u = (Usuario) obj;

            }

            @Override
            public void falha() {
                //Tratar a falha
            }
        });

        //*********************
    }

    @Override
    public void falha() {
        //Tratar a falha
    }

});
```